# Storing and retrieving from lists with custom structures in

Tags: c#

I'm having some trouble storing and retrieving items into a `list<>` with a custom structure.

My structure looks like this:

```
public class list_rss_parameters
{
    public string this_string { get; set; }
    public string title_start { get; set; }
    public string title_end { get; set; }
    public string description_start { get; set; }
    public string description_end { get; set; }
    public string link_start { get; set; }
    public string link_end { get; set; }
    public string publish_date_start { get; set; }
    public string publish_date_end { get; set; }
    public string author_start { get; set; }
    public string author_end { get; set; }
}
```

My stored procedure looks like this (and note that the variable names are the same as the custom Key names) Is this ok?

```
        //this is the last part of a custom method that returns a list
        List<list_rss_parameters> list_rss_items = new List<list_rss_parameters>();
        list_rss_items.Add(new list_rss_parameters()
        {
            this_string = this_string,
            title_start = title_start,
            title_end = title_end,
            description_start = description_start,
            description_end = description_end,
            link_start = link_start,
            link_end = link_end,
            publish_date_start = publish_date_start,
            publish_date_end = publish_date_end,
            author_start = author_start,
            author_end = author_end
        });

        return list_rss_items;
```

If the above two setups are correct, how do I pull items out of the List once I return it?

```
        List<list_rss_parameters> list_rss_parameters = new List<list_rss_parameters>();
        list_rss_parameters = f_discover_rss_parameters(rss);
        show(list_rss_parameters.Count.ToString());
        show(list_rss_parameters[0].ToString()); //does not show this_string 
        show(list_rss_parameters[this_string'] //does not show this_string 
        show(list_rss_parameters[0][this_string'];//does not show this_string
```

What am I doing wrong?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You want the `this_string` property of the first item in your list it seems:

```
show(list_rss_parameters[0].this_string);
```

Or show all of them:

```
foreach(var item in list_rss_parameters)
{ 
   Console.WriteLine(item.this_string);
}
```

As a side note your property names don't match the PascalCase naming convention for properties in .NET - so `this_string` really should be `ThisString`.